# Use unique in r with more than one logical condition

Tags: r, data.table, unique

Following data frame in `data.table`

```
df <- data.table (id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),
                  date=c("2013-11-22","2017-01-24","2017-06-24","2020-02-10","2011-01-03","2013-11-24","2015-01-24","2017-08-24"),
                  status=c("Former","Current","Former","Never","Current",NA,"Current","Former"))
df
id       date  status
1:  1 2013-11-22  Former
2:  1 2017-01-24 Current
3:  2 2017-06-24  Former
4:  2 2020-02-10   Never
5:  3 2011-01-03 Current
6:  3 2013-11-24    <NA>
7:  4 2015-01-24 Current
8:  4 2017-08-24  Former
```

I want to create a unique row per id with the following logicals. The latest `date` should be kept. If the `status` at latest date is `<NA>` or `Never` and there was another `status` for an earlier date, than the row with the earlier date should be kept.
I solved this with the following functions:

```
unique1 <- df[df$status %in% c("Former","Current"),]
unique1 <- unique1[,.SD[which.max(anydate(date))],by=.(id)]
unique_final <- unique(df[order(id,ordered(status,c("Former","Current","Never",NA)))],by='id')
unique_final[match(unique1$id,unique_final$id),]<-unique1
```

and get these results

```
id       date  status
1:  1 2017-01-24 Current
2:  2 2017-06-24  Former
3:  3 2011-01-03 Current
4:  4 2017-08-24  Former
```

Is there a way to combine these two logical subsetting steps? I would like to avoid creating a new data frame and than matching them.
I am working with `data.table` and a solution for a larger data set would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try:

```
library(data.table)

df[, .SD[
  if (all(status %in% c(NA, 'Never'))) .N
  else max(which(!status %in% c(NA, 'Never')))
  ], by = id]
```

Output:

```
   id       date  status
1:  1 2017-01-24 Current
2:  2 2017-06-24  Former
3:  3 2011-01-03 Current
4:  4 2017-08-24  Former
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` based solution. It recodes status so that current and former have the same level, and then sorts and takes the first row for each id

```r
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),
                 date=c("2013-11-22","2017-01-24","2017-06-24","2020-02-10","2011-01-03","2013-11-24","2015-01-24","2017-08-24"),
                 status=c("Former","Current","Former","Never","Current",NA,"Current","Former"))



df %>% 
  mutate(
    status = factor(status, levels = c("Never", "Former", "Current")),
    status2 = forcats::fct_recode(status, "Current" = "Former")
    ) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(desc(status2), desc(date)) %>% 
  select(-status2) %>% 
  slice(1)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   id [4]
#>      id date       status 
#>   <dbl> <chr>      <fct>  
#> 1     1 2017-01-24 Current
#> 2     2 2017-06-24 Former 
#> 3     3 2011-01-03 Current
#> 4     4 2017-08-24 Former
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `subset` + `ave`

```
subset(
  df[!df$status %in% c(NA, "Never"), ],
  as.logical(ave(date, id, FUN = function(x) x == max(x)))
)
```